# Cannot install any package using apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

It seems that some packages on my Ubuntu (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, lucid) are broken, preventing me from installing any new packages.  I have gone through similar questions in this site, but all proves useless. The following are some commands I tried along with the outputs:

```
'sudo apt-get install -f' OR 'sudo apt-get --fix-broken install':


Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gcalctool (5.30.0.is.5.28.2-0ubuntu3) ...


dpkg: error processing gcalctool (--configure):


 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

Setting up shared-mime-info (0.71-1ubuntu2) ...

Segmentation fault

dpkg: error processing shared-mime-info (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139

Setting up update-manager (1:0.134.12.1) ...

dpkg: error processing update-manager (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

Setting up vino (2.28.2-0ubuntu2.2) ...

dpkg: error processing vino (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245


No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up libgweather-common (2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...

dpkg: error processing libgweather-common (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgweather1:

 libgweather1 depends on libgweather-common (>= 2.24.0); however:

  Package libgweather-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgweather1 (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for menu ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 gcalctool

 shared-mime-info

 update-manager

 vino

 libgweather-common

 libgweather1

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


* 'sudo dkpg --configure -a':
Setting up shared-mime-info (0.71-1ubuntu2) ...

Segmentation fault

dpkg: error processing shared-mime-info (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139

Setting up gcalctool (5.30.0.is.5.28.2-0ubuntu3) ...

dpkg: error processing gcalctool (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

Setting up libgweather-common (2.30.0-0ubuntu1.1) ...

dpkg: error processing libgweather-common (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

Setting up vino (2.28.2-0ubuntu2.2) ...

dpkg: error processing vino (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

Setting up update-manager (1:0.134.12.1) ...

dpkg: error processing update-manager (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 245

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgweather1:

 libgweather1 depends on libgweather-common (>= 2.24.0); however:

  Package libgweather-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing libgweather1 (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Processing triggers for menu ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 shared-mime-info

 gcalctool

 libgweather-common

 vino

 update-manager

 libgweather1
```

Hope somebody could help me out, thanks in advance!

[EDIT]: I finally solved the problem by re-installing the system. In fact, I do not need to re-install, but just re-pair the system with all the data kept intact.

Comment: I would recommend you to consider an upgrade/reinstallation as Ubuntu 10 Desktop has a End of life since 9th May 2013.. This release is not up2date anymore at all since long time.

Answer (score 0):

As final resort I would go to Synaptic Package manager and try its "**Fix broken packages**" menu item under **Edit** menu. If that fails I will, in same program do check all broken packages and remove them (if it fails in synaptic just do it in terminal `sudo apt-get remove`) and then I do `sudo apt-get autoremove` and s`udo apt-get autoclean`

Before you try installing them you need to run `sudo apt-get update`

*By the way what was the last package you tried to install that broke things? That is important and should be part of your question!*

Comment: Thanks for replying. As it is a server machine, I cannot login with GUI.  The time when I noted this problem is when I tried to install rsync (`sudo apt-get install rsync`). I have tried all kinds of parameters with apt-get, they all give similar error with the packages shown in the original question.

Comment: what about reinstalling it? You just move your home folder under different partition and do reinstall again. It will only remove and reinstall system files and will not touch your data nor your config. By the way what was last package that screw system up?